The or operation in zero-knowledge proofs
If there are two operations: for witness ($a,r_1$), $ENC(a,r_1)\to C$; For witness ($b,r_2$), $ENC(b,r_2)\to C$.  In a situation where one of the above two needs to be satisfied, can the relevant zero-knowledge proof be defined as follows: $R\{witness=(x,r),statement=(C): (ENC(a,r_1)\to C) \vee (ENC(b,r_2)\to C)\}$ ?
